# Web Service Network Issue on Android using Flex

Tags: android, web-services, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am developing a mobile application to be deployed to both iOS and Android using Flash Builder and Flex. I'm at a point where I want to begin testing on a physical device as everything is working on the Flash Builder emulator.

When my app is loaded and the first view is displayed the following code is run.

```
creationComplete="initApp(event)

protected function initApp(event:FlexEvent):void
{               
    pricingAppWebService1.updateApp("RAMISAppUpdate");                          
}
```

My issue is that when I try and load the xml data from the server into the app using the Web Service (shown below), it results in a fault. This is strange as it works on the Flash Builder emulator.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:WebService id="pricingAppWebService" 
        wsdl="http://dev.ramislive.com/webservice/pricing.asmx?WSDL"
        result="dataSent_resultHandler(event)"
        fault="dataSent_faultHandler(event)" />    
</fx:Declarations>
```

When the app tries to get the xml data it hits the pricingAppWebService_faultHandler at which point the device displays a OK/Cancel pop-up box with the local IP of my machine displayed in a input text.

```
protected function pricingAppWebService_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
{
    trace(event.fault);
    navigator.pushView(MainMenu);           
}
```

The trace provides the following information in the Flash Builder Console.

```
[ RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request"
    faultDetail="Unable to load WSDL. 
    If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL    
    (http://dev.ramislive.com/webservice/pricing.asmx?WSDL)" ]
```

Naturally I considered the security settings on the device and the following exists in the android manifest file within src/Main-App.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

<strike>As a note I have looked at  [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665782/flex-webservice-and-android)  and the solution to my problem may be very similar. however i have tried replacing the domain with the IP address with no success. Apologies if this question is too vague, it's my first on the site. I've tried to provide as much detail as I possibly could short of the whole mxml file.</strike>

The issue seems to be throwing some kind of security issue - which is what I assume the pop-up box is. This however, is only speculation but my server notices a response after clicking OK and pressing the phone back button to try and reload the data.

Comment: Testing a mobile app in an emulator is like testing a mountain bike on pavement.  Are you sure your device is Internet connected?  Could your mobile operator be blocking the URL?  [or are you on wifi?]

Comment: Wifi is working normally as well as the internet on the device. Signal is also full.

Comment: Can you load that WSDL in the browser on your mobile device?  If so; then I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Yes and my web service is picking up a request, but only after i click ok on the pop-up box and press the back button.

Comment: I'm not sure what pop up box you're referring to.

Comment: I mention it after the declaration block. It appears to be a security issue.

Comment: I see it mentioned; a pop up box like that is anew one for me.  If you aren't accessing your local machine; why would you get a pop up box w/ your machine's IP Address?  I'm not much help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note this does not happen when testing using my internal wifi connection as the connection to the test computer is available (this is the IP in the box). To avoid the issue use the release version of the ipa instead. Otherwise do not worry it will not be shown in the final release build.

```
Project --> Export Release Build
```